# DataGridView slow update when there is a lot of data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Good day,

**Full problem:**

I have issue when updating binded data to datagrid.
It starts to work very slow when I have a 1 million row of data.
Updating in the start will only take 1-10 miliseconds for couple of rows.
When data increases to 1 million row, it will take 6-10 seconds on my pc.

I have **Thread** which receive data and **Timer** with a **Queue** which is updating the **DataGridView**.

```
DataTable globalTable = new DataTable();
BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
..
SBind.DataSource = globalTable;
dataGridViewMain.DataSource = SBind;
```

But if I use:

```
SBind.SuspendBinding();
//..Data Update..
SBind.ResumeBinding();
```

It will work fast, only problem is that

**DataGridViewMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** is always 0 after the resume.
How to make **SBind.ResumeBinding** to not change **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** value in **DataGridView**?
I can change this value after the update, but then vertical scroll bar is jumping around.

**Short problem:**

**ResumeBinding()** function in **BindingSource** is always changing **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** to zero.
How to fix that ResumeBinding() will leave **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** as it is.
Or maybe there is another good solution to update **DataGridView** quickly then there is a lot of data.

Comment: A user shouldn't have to deal with a million rows on the screen.  Give them a set they can work with.

Comment: In order to keep your UI responsive use a paging technique to retrieve data for display i.e. in blocks just larger than the displayed area. As the user scrolls through the data retrieve the next block of data, append it to your bound data source. Don't forget to remove data that is far beyond visual scope.

Comment: The DataGridView Control provides a [VirtualMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode) for this: *Virtual mode is designed for use with very large stores of data. When the VirtualMode property is true, you create a DataGridView with a set number of rows and columns and then handle the CellValueNeeded event to populate the cells [...]*